# 10 Ingredients to choose from for a sandwich. Total ways?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

**If, at the restaurant, it is possible to have on a pizza any combination of pepperoni, mushrooms, sausage, green peppers, onions, anchovies, salami, bacon, olives, and ground beef ($10$ different ingredients). How many different combinations exist?**

I assumed you can't pick an ingredient more than once, so my thinking was this:

I have $11$ choices for the first ingredient (I included the choosing of no topping), $10$ choices for the second ingredient, $9$ for the third, etc. So the total number of ways I can make a pizza is $11!$ but the book says the total number is $2^{10}$. Why?

Comment: Presumably the order in which you choose the toppings is not relevant, so you are just asked for the number of subsets of a set with $10$ elements.  You seem to be computing the number of ways to pick all $11$(?) toppings in order, which isn't what you were asked and which doesn't really make any sense (how can I first choose "no topping" and then start choosing toppings?)

Comment: Another way to think of this problem: you have $10$ possible toppings, each has $2$ options: you either take it or you don't. That's $2^{10}$ options.

Comment: I see!! thank you for your time @lulu and Dennis :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $10$ possible toppings on a pizza, and each of these toppings individually has $2$ different possibilities: on the pizza, or off the pizza. Hence the total number of possible pizzas is $2^{10}$.

I like to visualize it as $10$ "slots", one for each topping, and the number of options each individual topping can have - i.e. $2$, because each individual topping is a simple "yes" or "no" - goes into each slot. Then all $10$ of those $2$'s get multiplied to arrive at the final answer of $2^{10}$.

Notice this also counts the pizza with no toppings at all: it is simply the option where you have chosen "no" for every one of the $10$ options.

You would use factorials if you wanted to count *permutations* of toppings - but, in this case, the order you put the toppings on the pizza does not matter. You get the same pizza (presumably) whether you put the pepperoni on first or the mushrooms on first.

Comment: Thank you  for your time! I upvoted, will accept as soon as 5 min are over :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help! As a side note: in real life, I most definitely would insist on counting a pizza with the pepperoni on top of the mushrooms as different (and less tasty) than the other way around. :) Unfortunately, I don't think your stats homework is sensitive to this fact. But if it were, you'd have a whole other question on your hands: in this case, the total number of pizzas would be $\sum_{n=0}^{10} \frac{10!}{n!} = 9864101$. Wanna know something cool? This is equal to $\lfloor e\cdot10! \rfloor$... yep, that's the constant $e= 2.718...$, appearing where you least expect it.

Comment: that is mindblowing! hahaha